# Oracle Form Hanging Issue

Tags: forms, oracle12c, commit, freeze, inotifypropertychanged

Form got hanged after **Forms_ddl('commit')** code, and i am closing the whole application and opening again for the operation.
How we can resolve this issue.

This issue is happening occasionally.

There is no any blocking session in backend.